# Finding a percolation path

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks, algorithm

I would like to examine percolation on a random lattice. To be exact, I wish to find the minimum length of a 'bond' needed such that the leftmost site can be connected to the rightmost site.

Here is an example of the lattice:

```
randPts = Table[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2], {200}]; 
randPlot = ListPlot[randPts, 
                PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.0125]}, 
                PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
                AspectRatio -> 1, 
                Frame -> True]
```

[image: random lattice]

I have tried for a while to get this but have not had success. The basic plan was:

1. Define a bond length $R$
2. Look at each site one at a time. If another site(s) is within $R$ of a site, they will be in the same cluster. Each site will be in a cluster of 1 or more (obviously the larger $R$ chosen, the larger each cluster size)
3. Take a site. Does it bond with other sites? If so then combine the two clusters together.
4. Repeat step 3 for all sites.
5. At the end ask if the leftmost cite and the rightmost sites are included in the conglomerate cluster. If so, percolation has occurred.
6. Decrease $R$ and start over again until a threshold is found.

I think I am stuck somewhere in the step 3,4 area.
Here is some of what I've tried:
I have defined a module to find the distance between a site, `j`, and its nearest neighbor. The table, `t`, gives distance between `j` and all other sites:

```
minD[j_] := 
  Module[{},
    t = Table[{randPts[[i]], 
              Sqrt[(randPts[[j, 1]] - randPts[[i, 1]])^2 + (randPts[[j, 2]] - 
                 randPts[[i, 2]])^2]}, 
             {i, 1, Length[randPts]}];

    For[i = 1, i < Length[t] + 1, i++, 
      If[t[[i, 2]] == RankedMin[t[[All, 2]], 2], 
        coord[j] = t[[i, 1]] ]];
    Return[{coord[j]}];
  ];
```

This module takes the table of distances and picks out ones that are within the chosen bonding radius (1.5 here. the `y>0` condition to so to not count the same site):

```
  cluster[k_] := 
    Module[{},
      minD[k];
      Return[
        Table[Cases[t, {x_, y_} /; y < 1.5 && y > 0][[i]][[1]], 
              {i, 1, Length[Cases[t, {x_, y_} /; y < 1.5 && y > 0]]}]];
    ]
```

So `cluster[k]` gives the sites within the cluster that is centered at site `k`.
Now combining these clusters is what I am having a problem with. My idea was to start with a site and its cluster; find out what clusters that cluster intersects with and continue. I was not able to implement this correctly.

Another way to visualize or maybe solve the problem is in terms of increasing the site radius at each site until a percolation network is achieved:

```
 randMovie = 
   Manipulate[
    ListPlot[randPts, 
        PlotStyle -> {PointSize[x]}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
        Frame -> True], 
    {x, 0.00, 0.12, 0.002}]
```

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, `randPts` can be written `RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {200, 2}]`

Comment: That part is now copyable

Comment: Nice question.  Please note that the purpose of `Return` is not really returning values from a `Module`.  Instead of using `Module[{}, ...; Return[result]; ]` simply use `Module[{}, ...; result]` (not that lack of the final semicolon).  In general, you almost never need to use `Return` in Mathematica, and when you do, it's good to be aware of some unusual behaviour ...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A percolation network is just a kind of network, so I went in the direction of proposing a graph-theoretic approach. You seem to be measuring distances between nodes multiple times, but given the points don't move, you need only do it once:

```
ed = Outer[EuclideanDistance, randPts, randPts, 1];
```

You can get the positions of the nodes you are trying to connect like so:

```
leftmost = Position[randPts, {Min[randPts[[All, 1]] ], _}][[1, 1]]

rightmost = Position[randPts, {Max[randPts[[All, 1]] ], _}][[1, 1]]
```

Here is an auxiliary function that determines which nodes are no more than `r` distance from each other. I exclude zero distances to avoid the complication of self-loops.

```
linked[mat_?MatrixQ, r_?Positive] := Map[Boole[0 < # < r] &, mat, {2}]
```

It is easy to use this auxiliary function to create an adjacency matrix which can be visualised with the correct coordinates using the `VertexCoordinates` option.

```
gg = AdjacencyGraph[linked[ed, 2.], VertexCoordinates -> randPts]
```

[image: Graph visualisation]

Finding out whether the left-most and right-most points are connected is a matter of determining if `FindShortestPath` yields a non-empty result.

```
FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost]
(* ==> {56, 16, 126, 156, 142, 174, 65, 49, 23, 88, 6, 45, 122, 68, 131, 139, 80} *)
```

Let's put all this together. I am going to build the option to test if the network is a percolation network in the same function that visualises the network.

```
Options[isPercolationNetwork] = {ShowGraph -> False}

isPercolationNetwork[points : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, 
  r_?Positive, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{ed = Outer[EuclideanDistance, points, points, 1], 
   leftmost =  Position[points, {Min[points[[All, 1]] ], _}][[1, 1]], 
   rightmost = Position[points, {Max[points[[All, 1]] ], _}][[1, 1]]},
  With[{gg =  AdjacencyGraph[linked[ed, r], VertexCoordinates -> points]},
   If[OptionValue[ShowGraph],
    HighlightGraph[gg, PathGraph[FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost]]], 
    Length[FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost] ] > 1]]
  ]
```

If the option `ShowGraph` is `True`, it shows the graph and the connecting path; if it is `False`, it just returns `True` or `False`.

```
isPercolationNetwork[randPts, 2., ShowGraph -> True]
```

[image]

It is pretty straightforward to put all this together to find the minimum distance to create a percolation network.

```
minimumPercolationNetwork[points:{{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}..}, r0_?Positive] :=
 Module[{r = r0},
  While[isPercolationNetwork[randPts, r], r = r - 0.01]; 
  Print[r + 0.01]; 
  isPercolationNetwork[points, r + 0.01, ShowGraph -> True] ]
```

And the result:

```
minimumPercolationNetwork[randPts, 3.]
```

> ```
> 1.97
> ```
>
> [image]

Execution is reasonably fast: `Timing` of the above example was a bit above 6s on my machine, but it depends on the initial value you pick for `r`.

Comment: @BeauGeste, by the way, thank you for asking this question, I quite enjoyed working out an answer. Even after so many years using Mathematica, I'm amazed that so much is possible using so little code. I am not even a graph theorist and have never studied the topic.

Comment: excellent answer. This was along the lines of what I was attempting though I was not aware of all the graph theory functions until now (I was using Ifs and For statements, ugly I know). It really is amazing how simple it can be done (for you experts :)) in Mathematica compared to coding it

Comment: You can also do binary search on the r, reducing the complexity a bit more.

Comment: There is a really great example of Bond Percolation in Ch. 1 of Paul Wellin's book Programing with Mathematica. The example in the book uses GridGraph and RandomVariate[] with a BernoulliDistribution[] to assign bonds.  It's quite clever.

Comment: Have you calculated the supercritical probability $p<p_c$ where there is almost surely no path between the left side and the right side?

Comment: Can you explain me how the FindShortest path work? I am trying to create such algorithm for site percolation path [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120354/finding-all-minimal-paths-in-site-percolation).

Comment: @hhh - no, it's a built-in function, so you would be best asking Wolfram Research.

Answer (score 15):

An image-based method ... just a curiosity:

```
r = 10; (*half range*)
i = step = 1/100;
rndpts = RandomReal[{-r, r}, {200, 2}];

l = Graphics[{Thickness[.001 r], Line@{{{-r, -r}, {r, -r}}, {{r, r}, {-r, r}}}}];
lPlot[i_] := ListPlot[rndpts, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[i/(2 r)]}, 
                              PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}}, 
                              AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False];
t[i_] := MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate@Binarize@Rasterize@Show[lPlot[i], l]];

(* Now loop until the image top and bottom rows are connected *)
While[(mem = t[i])[[1, 1]] != mem[[-1, 1]], i += (r step)];
{i, t[i] // Colorize}
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty neat. Can you elaborate on your While statement? What is that doing to specify the percolation criterion?

Comment: @BeauGeste It is simply testing that the first pixel of the first row is in the same morphological component than the first pixel of the last row, so there is a connection between the top and bottom. Please note that I draw a line at the top and bottom of the graph to be able to test connectivity.

Comment: +1, I was thinking of doing the same when I read the question

Answer (score 12):

I learned about this technique from [Fred Simons](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/20253/fred-simons) on MathGroup, in a thread about computing connected components in graphs.  You'll find the full discussion thread [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/IRd7HVCx4ic/discussion).

Let's first create the sample dataset:

```
pts = RandomReal[10 {-1, 1}, {200, 2}];

ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts[[63]]], Point[pts[[90]]]}]
```

Then let's compute a distance matrix between points:

```
dst = Outer[EuclideanDistance, pts, pts, 1]; // Timing
```

(If you wish, you can speed this up by not computing every distance twice.  I chose to keep the code simple.)

Like @Verbeia, I chose to use a graph-apporach.  Let's create the set of possible edges in the graph and sort them by length.

```
edges = Subsets[Range@Length[pts], {2}];
edges = SortBy[edges, Extract[dst, #] &];
```

Let' choose the leftmost and rightmost points and name their indices `start` and `end`:

```
start = First@Ordering[pts[[All, 1]], 1];
end = First@Ordering[pts[[All, 1]], -1];
```

And now use Fred's solution with a little modification:

```
idx = Module[{f}, 
       Do[
        Set @@ f /@ (edges[[i]]); 
        If[f[start] === f[end], Return[i]], 
        {i, Length[edges]}]]
```

`idx` will give the edge of length $R$ (i.e. the minimal length edge that needs to be included).  In my case this length was 2.27:

```
Extract[dst, edges[[idx]]]

(* ==> 2.27273 *)
```

Here's a `Manipulate` that'll keep adding edges one by one, in order or increasing length, until we reach percolation.  The leftmost and rightmost vertices are highlighted in red.

```
Manipulate[
 HighlightGraph[
  Graph[Range@Length@pts, UndirectedEdge @@@ Take[edges, i], 
   VertexCoordinates -> pts], {start, end}], {i, 1, idx, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the performance of this solution is not good enough, you can speed it up a little bit using [the method I described in this MathGroup post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/IRd7HVCx4ic/_KsOP3ZXK_AJ).  The total running time for 200 points is ~0.2 seconds on my (slow) computer.

Comment: +1 I was writing a similar solution to this but you beat me. Serves me right for having lunch.

Comment: @Heike I almost went away to do something else for a while but I had a feeling that I needed to finish fast :-)

Answer (score 11):

As it might be interest to others than me, it seems a generalization to 3D of @Verbeia's post would be

```
linked[mat_?MatrixQ, r_?Positive] := Map[Boole[0 < # < r] &, mat, {2}]
Options[isPercolationNetwork] = Flatten[{ShowGraph -> False, Options[HighlightGraph]}];

isPercolationNetwork[points : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, r_?Positive, 
opts : OptionsPattern[]]:= 
Module[{ed = Outer[EuclideanDistance, points, points, 1],
leftmost = Position[points, {Min[points[[All, 1]]], _, _}][[1, 1]],
rightmost = Position[points, {Max[points[[All, 1]]], _, _}][[1, 1]]}, 
With[{gg = AdjacencyGraph[linked[ed, r], 
   VertexCoordinates -> points /. {_, y_, z_} -> {y, z}]}, 
If[OptionValue[ShowGraph], 
 HighlightGraph[gg,PathGraph[FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost]], 
  Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[HighlightGraph]]], 
Length[FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost]] > 1]]];

minimumPercolationNetwork[
points : {{_?NumericQ,_?NumericQ,_?NumericQ}..},r0_?Positive,opts: OptionsPattern[]]:= 
Module[{r = r0}, 
While[isPercolationNetwork[points, r],r =r-0.01];Print[r + 0.01];
isPercolationNetwork[points, r + 0.01, ShowGraph -> True, 
Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[HighlightGraph]]]]
```

so that

```
 randPts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {250, 3}];
```

and

```
 minimumPercolationNetwork[randPts, 0.2]
```

produces

```
 0.16
```

[image: a 3D percolating graph]

A version of the code which deals with different percolation directions, takes graph options and works in 2 and 3D  is given below

```
linked[mat_?MatrixQ, r_?Positive] :=  Map[Boole[0 < # < r] &, mat, {2}]
Options[isPercolationNetwork] = 
Flatten[{ShowGraph -> False, PercolationDirection -> 1,  
Options[HighlightGraph]}];
isPercolationNetwork[points : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, 
r_?Positive, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{ed = Outer[EuclideanDistance, points, points, 1], leftmost, 
rightmost},
If[OptionValue[PercolationDirection] == 1,
leftmost = Position[points, {Min[points[[All, 1]]], _}][[1, 1]];
rightmost = 
 Position[points, {Max[points[[All, 1]]], _}][[1, 1]];,
leftmost = Position[points, {_, Min[points[[All, 2]]]}][[1, 1]];
rightmost = Position[points, {_, Max[points[[All, 2]]]}][[1, 1]];
];
With[{gg = 
  AdjacencyGraph[linked[ed, r], VertexCoordinates -> points]}, 
If[OptionValue[ShowGraph], 
 HighlightGraph[gg, 
  PathGraph[FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost]], 
  Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[HighlightGraph]]], 
 Length[FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost]] > 1]]];

isPercolationNetwork[
points : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, r_?Positive, 
opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{ed = Outer[EuclideanDistance, points, points, 1], leftmost, 
rightmost},
Which[OptionValue[PercolationDirection] == 1,
leftmost = Position[points, {Min[points[[All, 1]]], _, _}][[1, 1]];
rightmost = 
 Position[points, {Max[points[[All, 1]]], _, _}][[1, 1]];,
OptionValue[PercolationDirection] == 2,
leftmost = Position[points, {_, Min[points[[All, 2]]], _}][[1, 1]];
rightmost = 
 Position[points, {_, Max[points[[All, 2]]], _}][[1, 1]];,
OptionValue[PercolationDirection] == 3,
leftmost = Position[points, {_, _, Min[points[[All, 3]]]}][[1, 1]];
rightmost = 
 Position[points, {_, _, Max[points[[All, 3]]]}][[1, 1]];
];
With[{gg = 
  AdjacencyGraph[linked[ed, r], 
   VertexCoordinates -> points /. {x_, y_, z_Real} -> {x, y}]},
If[OptionValue[ShowGraph],
 HighlightGraph[gg, 
  PathGraph[FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost]]
  (*GraphPlot3D[ggh,VertexCoordinateRules-> 
  Thread[Range[Length[points]]->points],Axes->True,AxesLabel->{x,
  y,z},ViewPoint->{0,0,500}]*)
  , 
  Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[HighlightGraph]]], 
 Length[FindShortestPath[gg, leftmost, rightmost]] > 1]]];
Clear[minimumPercolationNetwork];
Options[minimumPercolationNetwork] = 
Flatten[{ShowGraph -> True, PercolationDirection -> 1,  
Options[HighlightGraph]}];
minimumPercolationNetwork[points : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, 
r0_?Positive, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
Module[{r = r0},
While[isPercolationNetwork[points, r, 
PercolationDirection -> OptionValue[PercolationDirection]], 
r = r - 0.01];
{r + 0.01,
isPercolationNetwork[points, r + 0.01, ShowGraph -> True, 
 PercolationDirection -> OptionValue[PercolationDirection], 
 Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[HighlightGraph]]] // 
Rasterize[#, ImageResolution -> 150] &}]

 minimumPercolationNetwork[
 points : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, r0_?Positive, 
 opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{r = r0},
 While[isPercolationNetwork[points, r, 
 PercolationDirection -> OptionValue[PercolationDirection]], 
 r = r - 0.01];
 {r + 0.01,
 isPercolationNetwork[points, r + 0.01, ShowGraph -> True, 
 PercolationDirection -> OptionValue[PercolationDirection],
 Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[HighlightGraph]]] // 
 Rasterize[#, ImageResolution -> 150] &}] 

 randPts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {150, 3}];

 Column[{minimumPercolationNetwork[randPts, 
 1.5/(Length[randPts])^(1/3), Frame -> True, 
 PercolationDirection -> 1][[2]],
 minimumPercolationNetwork[randPts, 1.5/(Length[randPts])^(1/3), 
 Frame -> True, PercolationDirection -> 2][[2]],
 minimumPercolationNetwork[randPts, 1.5/(Length[randPts])^(1/3), 
 Frame -> True, PercolationDirection -> 3][[2]]}]
```

Comment: What is the 0.16?

Comment: @hhh The minimum distance to create a percolation network, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Do you know is there any way to the model a square lattice as a graph in order to use the FindShortestPath command? I am trying to model site percolation [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120354/finding-all-minimal-paths-in-site-percolation).