# Using Gather to rearrange my data

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a list of elements:

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 6}, 
 {5, 9}, {9, 13}, {10,11}, {11, 12}, {11, 15}, {15, 16}}
```

I have to divide it into sublists, so that:

```
#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] || #1[[1]] == #2[[2]] || #1[[2]] == #2[[1]] || #1[[2]] == #2[[2]] &
```

i.e. at the end I need to obtain:

```
{{{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 9}, {9, 13}},
 {3, 7}, {4, 8}, {{10,11}, {11, 12}, {11, 15}, {15, 16}}}
```

However, I cannot find a solution to do it with `Gather`.  How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Your have not defined your desired goal sufficiently for anyone to be able to help you. Are `#1` and `#2` your sublists? Are there only 2 sublists? As far as I can tell, you want to divide a list of pairs into two 2-length lists where all elements are equal, which makes no sense. You will want to edit your question.

Comment: @Brett That's the only reasonable interpretation.  I'm the editing the question to change `&&` to `||`.

Answer (score 13):

Can be done with some graph computation.

```
In[585]:= gg = Graph[Apply[UndirectedEdge, ll, {1}]];

In[586]:= comps = ConnectedComponents[gg]

Out[586]= {{1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 13}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}, {10, 11, 12, 15, 16}}

In[587]:= Map[
 Cases[ll, aa_ /; MemberQ[aa, Alternatives @@ #]] &, comps]

Out[587]= {{{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 9}, {9, 13}}, {{3, 
   7}}, {{4, 8}}, {{10, 11}, {11, 12}, {11, 15}, {15, 16}}}
```

This could be made more efficient, in that last step. Only matters if you have to do this on much bigger such lists.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much! Actually I am doing all this stuff in order to find a percolation threshold :) so now I know how to deal with such problems!

Comment: @anastasiiia [This question about a percolation problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5152/finding-a-percolation-path) may be of interest then.

Comment: Alternately: `(EdgeList[Subgraph[gg, #]] & /@ comps) /. UndirectedEdge -> List`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a different approach using `Gather` and `FixedPoint`:

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 6}, 
       {5, 9}, {9, 13}, {10,11}, {11, 12}, {11, 15}, {15, 16}};

gather = Join @@@ Gather[#, Flatten[#] ⋂ Flatten[#2] =!= {} &] &;

FixedPoint[gather, List /@ lst]

(* output: {{{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 9}, {9, 13}},
            {{3, 7}},
            {{4, 8}},
            {{10, 11}, {11, 12}, {11, 15}, {15, 16}}}  *)
```

Comment: thank you very much for helping me! I used the approach of the first and the second suggestions, since it is mostly related to my research (graph theory), but I am sure that Gather can be a very good alternative.

Comment: @Heike That is a very nice approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

In versions 10.2+, @Daniel's approach can be used more directly using [RelationGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html?q=RelationGraph) with the relation `IntersectingQ` (thanks: Carl Woll). `ConnectedComponents` of the resulting graph gives the desired result:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 6}, {5, 9}, {9, 13}, {10,11}, 
   {11, 12}, {11, 15}, {15, 16}};

ConnectedComponents[RelationGraph[IntersectingQ, data]]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 9}, {9, 13}},
>      {{10, 11}, {11, 12}, {11, 15}, {15, 16}},
>      {{4, 8}},
>      {{3, 7}}}

Comment: `IntersectingQ` instead of `Intersection[##] =!= {}&` is simpler.

Comment: Right, thank you @Carl!