# Is there a way to convert an image into a Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, matrix, image

I'm trying to convert an image with several overlapping dots into a `Graph`. The goal is to be able to derive the Kirchhoff matrix for the randomly created "network of resistors" a.k.a dots with the function `KirchhoffMatrix[]`. Any thoughts or ideas?

Here's the image I'm trying to extract the graph from:
[image]

Haha, sorry I suppose I have been pretty vague with this question. I am currently researching percolation simulations. The dots in the image represent metallic particles. The dots the overlap represent metallic particles connected via a resistor. We randomize the dots on the screen, group the ones that are touching with `MorphologicalComponents[] // Colorize` , and then we Isolate the 'BackBone Cluster' a.k.a the largest component with `DeleteSmallComponents[]`. We check to see if the cluster spans all the way from the top to the bottom and if it does, the sample percolated. We are then trying to find the conductance of the sample from the BackBone cluster. We have been using the Finite Element Method for this, which requires the `KirchhoffMatrix[]`.

Your answer, Vitaliy Kaurov, looks like it will very thoroughly answer my question. I'm going to test things before I accept it but thank you for putting so much time into it!!

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping"? Contiguous pixels?

Comment: I can see how dots can be resistors in a network. Their role in the graph will be that of edges, but what will determine the vertices?

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5152/8 I can see how the dots are *vertices* but how do you know which ones are connected? That's where the percolation approach might be relevant.

Comment: Could you please give some details/background to your problem, maybe some references? I am curious.

Comment: It's not clear to me either how you get from this image to a graph.  Please explain a bit.  What are those dots in the image?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If you guys ever write a paper or put results on a website - I'd love to see it - let me know.

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov Will do, Vitaliy! By the way, I want to let you know that it was thanks to your Question about effeciently updating SparseArrays that we finished our Matrix based simulator :)

Comment: I added more info at the end of my current answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**==== Method 1 ===**

Here is a way to get a graph from an image. [**`MorphologicalGraph`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalGraph.html) can get you started.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HXZ5.png"];
g = MorphologicalGraph[img]
```

[image]

And here is your `KirchhoffMatrix` of the graph. Please note that `MatrixPlot` averages values for the best visual representation, - actual plot would be too detailed to be a good representation.

```
m = KirchhoffMatrix[g]; MatrixPlot[m]
```

[image]

A good guess is that your graph, due to its random nature, not all entirely connected. This maybe important in your case, because with no connection you have no conductance. Here is the way to find all connected components, highlight them and compute their own `KirchhoffMatrix`.

```
cc = ConnectedComponents[g];
index = Length /@ ConnectedComponents[g];
ctrl = Sort[MapThread[Rule, {cc, index}], #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &];
Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow[{HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, n], 
    GraphStyle -> "LargeNetwork"], 
   MatrixPlot[KirchhoffMatrix[Subgraph[g, n]], 
    ColorFunction -> "DarkBands"]}, 
  ImageSize -> 600], {{n, ctrl[[1, 1]], "Vertex number"}, ctrl}, 
 FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Let's do some math now. Here is a famous property:

> **The number of times 0 appears as an eigenvalue in the** 
>   **`KirchhoffMatrix` is the number of connected components** 
>   **in the graph.**

The number of connected comments (separate sub-graphs) is found as

```
 ConnectedComponents[g] // Length
```

> 159

And as you can see it is equal to the number of zero eigenvalues :

```
 ev = Chop[Eigenvalues[N@m]]; Count[ev, 0]
```

> 159

Isn't it great to see programming and math matching up perfectly?

Here is the way to list all connected sub-graphs separately. Mouse-over will give `KirchhoffMatrix`.

```
Tooltip[#, 
   MatrixPlot[KirchhoffMatrix[Subgraph[g, #]], 
    ColorFunction -> "DarkBands", 
    ImageSize -> 200]] & /@ (Subgraph[g, #, ImageSize -> 80, 
     VertexSize -> 0] & /@ ctrl[[All, 1]])
```

[image]

Note some extra image processing before `MorphologicalGraph` would result in different graphs. For example finding first `SkeletonTransform` or `DistanceTransform` would change the game:

```
GraphicsRow[{DistanceTransform[Dilation[img, 3]] // ImageAdjust,
  SkeletonTransform[img]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

So if you now apply `MorphologicalGraph` function to these images you of course will get different graphs as result. This maybe useful because there is no exact guarantee that `MorphologicalGraph` will give you always what you need in all cases, especially with low-res images. Below is an example of possible issue - with real question being where exactly is the boundary between these two cases?

```
Grid@{{r = .6; 
   img = ColorNegate@
     Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, r], Disk[{.5, .9}, r], Disk[{1, 0}, r]}],
   MorphologicalGraph[img, VertexSize -> .1]},
  {r = 1.2; 
   img = ColorNegate@
     Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, r], Disk[{.5, .9}, r], Disk[{1, 0}, r]}],
   MorphologicalGraph[img, VertexSize -> .1]}}
```

[image]

So this is just the word of caution - **you may need some image pre-processing before you get your `MorphologicalGraph`**. Or you may use something else - see method below.

**==== Method 2 ===**

This is just an outline, not complete solution:

1) [**This question**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5152/finding-a-percolation-path) and answers by @Verbeia and @Szabolcs and Fred Simons on MathGroup are a starting point

2) They work only if you know center and radius of every point in your image - which you do NOT

3) You can get center and radius of every point by using for example [**`ComponentMeasurements`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) function. Then you can apply methods by @Verbeia and @Szabolcs and Fred Simons on MathGroup.

- **Example 1**: [**This Wolfram Blog**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) gives code for finding what you need even in the case of overlapping particles, like this (image - courtesy of Wolfram Research):

[image]

- **Example 2** The talk [**A Speed Date with Mathematica by Jon McLoone**](http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2011/presentations/) has video and notebook with code solving a similar applied problem (image - courtesy of Wolfram Research):

[image]

Comment: +1 for `SkeletonTransform` - what other nuggets of amazingness are hidden away in little-used corners of this language?

Comment: FWIW: since the Kirchhoff matrix is symmetric anyway, one could just use `MatrixRank[]` to help in computing the number of zero eigenvalues: `Length[m] - MatrixRank[m]`.

Comment: @Verbeia thanks ;-) Added another "corner" `DistanceTransform`.