# How to generate a Graph from a picture of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, image

I have a picture like this

[image]

I can get this graph's vertexes

```
mor = MorphologicalBinarize[img // ColorNegate] // 
     DeleteSmallComponents // ColorNegate // MorphologicalComponents;
selectmor = 
  SelectComponents[
    mor, {"AreaRadiusCoverage", "Count"}, # > 0.78 && #2 < 1000 &] // 
   Image;
mask = Graphics@
  Point@ComponentMeasurements[selectmor, "Centroid"][[All, 2]]
```

[image]

Or get its edges

```
fillimg = 
  FillingTransform[
     MorphologicalBinarize[img // ColorNegate] // 
        DeleteSmallComponents // Thinning // Pruning, 
     selectmor // Binarize] // Thinning // Pruning;
lines = ImageLines[fillimg, MaxFeatures -> 200, 
   Method -> {"Hough", "Segmented" -> True}];
Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line /@ lines}]
```

[image]

This my current work.  May be you can realize it by more smart method.  My target is not a `Image` but a `Graph`.  So how to rebuild the `Graph` by this `vertex` and this `edge`?

---

**Update:**
After the M.R.'s comments (Thanks for your comment), we can use the `MorphologicalGraph` to get the embryo of graph.

```
fillimg // MorphologicalGraph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &
```

[image]

But it have a low precision.  So How to refine it?

Comment: This has been asked before I believe, check out this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-image-into-a-graph/6787#6787

Comment: And http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/how-to-convert-an-image-to-a-graph-and-get-the-positions-of-the-edges

Comment: @M.R. Thanks for your  `MorphologicalGraph` in your link.But its precision is very poor when I try to do it.It will introduce many superfluous vertex.

Comment: @M.R. After I read all your related links,I think this problem is a essential question still.

Comment: Updates to questions are a mean for clarifying them, not for scope drifting

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I'm sorry.You are right.I should maintain the acceptance.My cancel just for attracting more people to solve it.So do you mean I should post another question?

Comment: Oh, you misunderstood me. The problem isn't the acceptance, but that people who already visited your question won't probably come again just to read some clarification. So this way you lose (instead of gain) audience

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Thanks.I think I need a new `p` by the line's gradient to judge the relation of two vertexes.But I cost an afternoon of time and fail to it.

Comment: @yode Post another question!

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Poor English.But I post it just now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
i       = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qofeF.png"];
vertexI = SelectComponents[i, "Count", 10 < # < 100 &];
vxPos   = ComponentMeasurements[vertexI, "Centroid"];
lines   = Subsets[Range@Length@vxPos, {2}];
linePos = lines /. vxPos;
ti@x_  := Total@Flatten@ImageData@Binarize@x

p = Position[ti@i - ti@Show[i, Graphics@Line@#] & /@ linePos, x_ /; x < 100];

Graphics[{Red, Line[Extract[linePos, p]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graph[Range@Length@vxPos, UndirectedEdge @@@ Extract[lines, p], 
      VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, 
      VertexCoordinates -> vxPos]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Congratulations to your doctorate

Comment: @eldo [You, you may say. I'm a dreamer, but I'm not the only one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwUGSYDKUxU&feature=youtu.be&t=1m35s) :)

Comment: Bash-wise: Does that mean all Drs are evil dark lords? The helmet fits your avatar perfectly :D

Comment: @YvesKlett Not necessarily all doctors.Just those who consider their academic titles as important as their names

Comment: Getting a Ph.D. made me finally realise how truly useless titles are, and how much unnecessary trouble it causes trying to choose the right one for oneself and others in different situations. Now I never use any at all.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I was pondering exactly about that when I changed my username

Comment: So cool job!!Your `p` impressed me deeply.Of course you can use `ImageMeasurements[binarizeimage, "Total"]` to substitute `ti` I think.Thanks again.

Comment: @yode Thanks! I didn't use `ImageMeasurements` because one of the images is binarized and the other is RGB. The resulting code was uncomfortable (not a big deal, anyway)

Comment: Good Dr. ! ^_^ ~

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Dear Dr.,I find a flaw in your nice work in some situation.So I put a update2 in my question.Sorry for my further request to a finished question.And If you can rebuild this image with curve,I will give you another 100 bounties.

Comment: @Oleksandr https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdi3FIrsHgo

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Very funny, Mr.