# Digitalizing hand-written graphs (vertices and edges)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, drawing

Is there a way to draw a graph (vertices and edges) on a piece of paper, scan it (or take a photo) and turn it into a more computer-friendly description? (such as list of neighbours). It's much easier to draw something on a paper or a whiteboard and then be able to instantly perform some algorithms to extract certain features of desired graph, rather than writing list of neighbours manually or drawing graphs inside a special software.

Comment: Have a look at `MorphologicalGraph` in the documentation. This might be a good starting point for a solution.

Comment: Is this what you need? [How to generate a Graph from a picture of a graph?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102262/5478)