# How can you delete a list of vertices from a GridGraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a grid graph:

[image]

and delete the vertices `{3, 4, 5, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 26, 27, 30}` and preserve the structure. There is the `VertexDelete` command but I am unable to get it working while preserving the structure.

```
SeedRandom[10801];
dimension = 5;
coDimension = 10;
percProbability = 0.7;
deleteMe = 
 Pick[Table[i, {i, 1, 30}], Table[RandomReal[] > 0.5, {i, 30}]]

G = GridGraph[{dimension, coDimension}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  ImagePadding -> 30]
```

**How can you delete a list of vertices from a GridGraph?**

*p.s. Related to this percolation puzzle [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120354/finding-all-minimal-paths-in-site-percolation) for which I want to solve this.*

Comment: "while preserving the structure." <- What do you mean by "structure"?

Comment: @Szabolcs I want to get the vertex-induced graph of the grid-graph above where the vertices of the list and the incident edges deleted -- and I want to see the graph as a grid, not all vertices jammed together.

Comment: If you mean vertex coordinates, do `g = SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g]]` before deleting vertices.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you! Over 4 months, I haven't been able to do this and now I learnt it :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Big Thank You to Szalbocs! You need to have

```
G = SetProperty[G, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[G]];
```

just before

```
VertexDelete[G, deleteMe]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[10801];
dimension = 5;
coDimension = 10;
percProbability = 0.7;
deleteMe = 
  Pick[Table[i, {i, 1, 30}], Table[RandomReal[] > 0.5, {i, 30}]];
G = GridGraph[{dimension, coDimension}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  ImagePadding -> 30]
G = SetProperty[G, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[G]];
VertexDelete[G, deleteMe]
```

and on the percolation example with more efficient `deteleMe` as given by m_goldberg

```
SeedRandom[10801];
dimension = 5;
coDimension = 10;
percProbability = 0.7;
deleteMe = 
 With[{n = dimension coDimension}, 
  Pick[Range[n], Thread[RandomReal[1., n] > percProbability]]]
G = GridGraph[{dimension, coDimension}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  ImagePadding -> 30]
G = SetProperty[G, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[G]];
VertexDelete[G, deleteMe]
```

where now removing vertices and its incident edges with percolation probability equal 0.7 over all edges (instead of just a subset)

[image]

The two examples demonstrate the `SetProperty` to preserve the structure.